# SQL query: How to count frequency over a many-to-many relation?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, frequency-analysis, frequency-distribution

I have a table for blogposts and a table for tags, with a many-to-many relation between them.

How can I extract the most frequent tag across a *subset* of blogposts? (e.g. only those from the past year)
Is there a way to extract the frequencies of all the tags associated with the blogposts subset?

Thanks

Edit: my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `access` varchar(1),
    `linked_created` datetime
)
;

CREATE TABLE `blogpost_tags` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `blogpost_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `tag_id` integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`blogpost_id`, `tag_id`)
)
;

CREATE TABLE `blogpost` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `title` varchar(50),
    `body` varchar(500)
)
;
```

Comment: You should show us your table design (or even better, a small table design to exactly illustrate the problem).  With it, we can help a lot easier (i.e. without as much guessing).

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Now that schema has been provided, removed my sample schema and just posted the query)

```
Select T.name, Count(*) As UseCount
From Tag As T
    Join BlogPost_Tag As BPT
        On BPT.tag_Id = T.Id
    Join BlogPost As BP
        On BP.Id = BPT.blogpost_id
Where BP.Title Like '...'
Group By T.name
```